# EA no database type when adding stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, enterprise-library, enterprise-architect

I see this official page http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/data_modeling/storedprocedureindividualclass.htm . I want to add stored procedure to my project, there is no database to select from , i just have this:
[image]

This is the EA which I am using.

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you show does not refer to a database but to the DBMS that you are using. It is more than likely that this feature was introduced after version 7. You may want to download a new trial version of the current version (10) to see if this is the case.

For your design it may not matter too much, as long as you write your stored procedure in whatever target DBMS you are working on.